# I get an error of ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 0

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to run this code in python but I receive this error : `ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 0`.
I have read a CSV file and want to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import sort

## import data set

data = pd.read_csv('trial_incomes.csv')

print(data.head(10))

def H_function(*args):
    Hash=[]
    for i in args:
        hashedfunction=(6*(i)+1) % 5
        Hash+=hashedfunction
        print (Hash)
        
H_function(data)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [58], in <cell line: 9>()
      5         Hash+=hashedfunction
      6         print (Hash)
----> 9 H_function(data)

Input In [58], in H_function(*args)
      3 for i in args:
      4     hashedfunction=(6*(i)+1) % 5
----> 5     Hash+=hashedfunction
      6     print (Hash)

File ~\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py:72, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     68             return NotImplemented
     70 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 72 return method(self, other)

File ~\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:107, in OpsMixin.__radd__(self, other)
    105 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__radd__")
    106 def __radd__(self, other):
--> 107     return self._arith_method(other, roperator.radd)

File ~\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:7584, in DataFrame._arith_method(self, other, op)
   7581 axis = 1  # only relevant for Series other case
   7582 other = ops.maybe_prepare_scalar_for_op(other, (self.shape[axis],))
-> 7584 self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=None)
   7586 new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)
   7587 return self._construct_result(new_data)

File ~\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py:283, in align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis, flex, level)
    279         raise ValueError(
    280             f"Unable to coerce list of {type(right[0])} to Series/DataFrame"
    281         )
    282     # GH17901
--> 283     right = to_series(right)
    285 if flex is not None and isinstance(right, ABCDataFrame):
    286     if not left._indexed_same(right):

File ~\miniforge3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py:240, in align_method_FRAME.<locals>.to_series(right)
    238 else:
    239     if len(left.columns) != len(right):
--> 240         raise ValueError(
    241             msg.format(req_len=len(left.columns), given_len=len(right))
    242         )
    243     right = left._constructor_sliced(right, index=left.columns)
    244 return right

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 0
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?  If it is on the `print(data.head(10))`, as I suspect, then it means your CSV file either did not exist or did not contain any data.  Also, you will probably want to pass one column into `H_function`.  Right now, you're passing the whole data frame.

Comment: @TimRoberts : no , print (head.data(10)) is working well, i get thsi error on next part (H-function) , how my code should be changed please ? (my data set has one column of income )

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre], and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : i have uploaded the whole error

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put this content **in the question itself**, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there's so much you haven't told us, but here's the problem.

Your handling of the DataFrame is wrong.  You are passing the dataframe to your function with the parameter list `(*args)`.  That turns the dataframe into an iterator, and when you iterate a dataframe, it comes out as a set of columns.  So, `args` ends up as a list containing the single column of data, as a pandas Series.  When you do `for i in args:`, `i` ends up as that whole column.  You end up doing your math on the whole column, but when you try to add the column to the list, that operation is not supported.

I'm ASSUMING your CSV file has one column of numbers, and you want to the math in your loop on every row of that column.  If so, this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('x.csv')

print(data.head(10))

def H_function(*args):
    Hash=[]
    for i in args:
        hashedfunction=(6*(i)+1) % 5
        Hash.append(hashedfunction)
    return Hash
        
print(H_function(data['income']))
```

With this input:

```
income
1234.00
2345.00
3456.00
4576.00
12000.00
24000.00
36000.00
48000.00
60000.00
921.11
922.22
933.33
```

I get this output:

```
     income
0   1234.00
1   2345.00
2   3456.00
3   4576.00
4  12000.00
5  24000.00
6  36000.00
7  48000.00
8  60000.00
9    921.11
[0     0.00
1     1.00
2     2.00
3     2.00
4     1.00
5     1.00
6     1.00
7     1.00
8     1.00
9     2.66
10    4.32
11    0.98
Name: income, dtype: float64]
```

Comment: thanks for your Response, how i should pass 'income'  to my function , you mean I should make this : income=[1234.00,2345.00,3456.00,4576.00,12000.00,24000.00,36000.00,48000.00,60000.00,921.11,922.22,933.33] before passing data to my function ?? @Tim Roberts